# XNA - just a few more characters accepted in a SpriteFont

Tags: xna, c#, fonts

I have a SpriteFont in XNA, which has the standard 126 characters that are usable.

However i would like to use the "ಠ" symbol in the game.

So is there anyway of adding just a few more symbols that the spritefont accepts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modify the sprite font file. It's XML. Double click it in Visual Studio.

Towards the bottom of the default file is a the following:

```
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#32;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

Your character is unicode code point U+0CA0, which in decimal is 3232. So add another character region tag that contains it:

```
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#3232;</Start>
    <End>&#3232;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
```

This assumes that the ಠ symbol exists in the font you are using.

Comment: ahhh yes, a second region... duh, didn't think of that :P
I was just trying multiple Start and End tags...

Comment: My solution was better :p